# Determine source of Database Event in Firebase RealTime Database and Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, subscription

I have a Flutter app using Firebase Realtime database.  I have created subscriptions to add, change, and delete for a node.

I would like to determine if the DatabaseEvent received for these subscriptions was generated by the local application, or by something else (for example, a direct edit using the Firebase Console.)

I know I could probably store some information when I issue the database add, change or delete, and then when I receive the event compare to see if the same item referenced, but I was hoping to see if there was some information in the Event itself (or somewhere else) that would tell me this.

Anyone have an idea?

I have examined the DatabaseEvent object returned when the subscriptions fire, but I don't see any information that could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*firebaser here*

There is nothing built in for this in the Firebase Realtime Database SDK or in any of its other APIs. If you want to know the source of the data, you'll have to track it yourself.

One of our early demo apps for a shared whiteboard held a list of the push keys for all its pending writes, so that it could filter those in its listener (as it had already drawn the local strokes before even sending them to the database). But there are many other valid approaches for this too.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  I am coding to keep a queue of database Change/Update/Delete actions so when the event comes back, I can check if the key of the child in question is in the queue.  If not, then the event was originated elsewhere.  I don't think this will be 100%, but maybe close enough.